# Capacitor discharge

Tags: capacitor

So I came across [this](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/voltage-doubler-circuit-diagram) article on CircuitDigest where they explained the functionality of a voltage doubler designed with capacitors. The circuit shown is the following:

[image]

At first capacitor C3 is charged to 5v (source voltage) when Q (the output of the 555 timer in astable mode) is low. Afterwards, when Q is set to high the diode D1 avoids C3 from being discharged (since the plates now have a direct path to connect to each other) and instead it gets discharged via ground passing through capacitor C4 thus adding the charge to C4 and therefore doubling the voltage (on C4) at that instance.

What seems odd to me is how come the capacitor C3 was able to discharge? Don’t the plates of the capacitor need to be directly connected to each other? In this case it looks like C3 is being discharged through ground and not through the other plate of the capacitor. How is this possible?

If anyone cloud clear this out for me I’ll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: A capacitor will charge/discharge if a current passes through it. In your opinion, will a current pass through the capacitor?

Comment: @immibis At first I would have said no, as in no current passes through the capacitor C3 since there is no direct connection between the plates. This however doesn’t seem to be the case... I thought that a capacitor could only be discharged through its plates. After all, the potential difference is defined between the plates not between one plate and ground, right?

Comment: If the plates have to be directly connected in order for a current to flow, then how would it charge? And yes, that's why it's a potential difference and not just a potential.

Comment: Current merely *appears* to flow through a capacitor (if you treat it as a black box you can't see into.) But avoid that thought. Suppose pin 3 is at ground and \$C_3\$ has no stored charge (\$0\:\text{V}\$ across it.) Then \$D_1\$ will charge it up (which requires current and time.) Once charged (to about \$4.5\:\text{V}\$, let's say), pin 3 is driven upward to \$5\:\text{V}\$. Since the negative end of \$C_3\$ is attached to pin 3, this means the positive end of \$C_3\$ must be at about \$9.5\:\text{V}\$ now (add capacitor voltage to pin voltage.) \$D_2\$ charges \$C_4\$ to \$9\:\text{V}\$.

Comment: Hey @jonk, it looks to me you have answered the question. Answering in comments is discouraged on this board, care to just turn that comment in an answer?

Comment: Current flows through a capacitor - electrons don't.

Comment: @VladimirCravero When writing an answer, I try to push towards a more comprehensive view. If I don't have the time or inclination, I may contribute a comment that provides a hopefully useful direction to consider. Some here will just write quick, dashed off answers. Some, even just one sentence! But I want my answers to contribute beyond the value of the OP alone and to provide context. It's not worth it otherwise to me as there is already too much garbage in the world. My comment didn't meet my standards for an answer. So it was offered as a comment.

Comment: I understand your PoV @jonk, and while you clearly are experienced enough and you provided a right comment, comments should only be used to ask for clarification as they cannot be downvoted, basically. It's not much about your contribution, which in my personal view was positive in this case, but more about the fact that other, less experienced people may leave bad comments that cannot be properly treated.

Comment: @VladimirCravero I appreciate the time you are taking to make your point. But I simply disagree with the conclusions. I can only control myself and I can only make my own choices. I have chosen to only add answers that meet my own standards for an answer (applicability to more than the questioner and the scope and breadth required for that) and when I lack the time for it but still have the time for a smaller response and want to offer help to just the questioner, then I write it as a comment. I'm not responsible to police others. Just myself. I respect your viewpoint. But it's yours.

Comment: Hey @jonk, I understand your point. I did not want to try and convince you to change your mind, just show you another vision. Best of luck, and thanks for the contribution and time you put in this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C3 discharges via the power supply. When the output of the 555 is high, you have basically the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH2xzL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q28 is conducting, so current can flow clockwise around this loop. The voltage on C3 is in series with the power supply, so the combined voltage is enough to forward bias D2 and push charge onto C4.

C3 discharges by virtue of the fact that current flows **out** of its positive terminal, through D2, C4, the power supply and Q28, back to its negative terminal. Note that the same current is flowing **in** to the positive terminal of C4, charging it.

Internals of the 555 are from the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf).

Comment: Perfectly explained, thanks. Just one thing, how is it that the current enters the negative side of the power supply and exits through the positive side? Aren't they suppose to be isolated since that would otherwise create a short? Thanks

Comment: No. That's exactly what the power supply does all the time!

Comment: You’re right! Everything makes sense now. Thanks